# How to format data from string type to a valid JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I got a string type data like below.

```
{
  "Description": "some descriptions",
  "Customers": {
        "Customer": {
              "Name": "John Smith",
              "Phone": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "Customer": {
              "Name": "Chris Lee",
              "Phone": "555-666-7890"
        }
  },
  "Addresses": {
        "Address": {
              "City": "New York"
        }
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble with converting it to a valid JSON Object like below.

```
{
      "Description": "some descriptions",
      "Customers": [
            {
                  "Name": "John Smith",
                  "Phone": "123-456-7890"
            },
            {
                  "Name": "Chris Lee",
                  "Phone": "555-666-7890"
            }
      ],
      "Addresses": [
            {
              "City": "New York"
            }
      ]
}
```

What I tried so far is using **JSON.parse()**, but I got no luck. The result looks like

```
{
      "Description": "some descriptions",
      "Customers": {
            "Customer": {
                  "Name": "John Smith",
                  "Phone": "123-456-7890"
            }
      },
      "Addresses": {
            "Address": {
                  "City": "New York"
            }
      }
}
```

You can see, I'm missing one customer record.

I can NOT change the content of the data at all. If I could I will make the customers as an array, that should solve the problem, but I can NOT.

I also thought about using javascript regular expression to do it, no luck.

Any ideas will help, thanks.

Comment: Just to clear things up a bit... What you have is a JSON string, and you're wanting to change the structure of the data within it. You don't have string type data or want a JSON Object.

Comment: Probably it fails because your source JSON contains `"Customers": { cust1, cust2 }` instead of `"Customers": [ cust1, cust2 ]`. It needs to be an array in the source, if you want an array in the result.

Comment: Fix the source, not the symptoms.

Comment: @str OP pretty explicitly said that he could not

Comment: You should never use regexp to interact with a valid json string. Convert it to an object, manipulate it, then if you really need it back as a json string, stringify the object.

Comment: @KevinB But the string isn't valid JSON, it has doubled key names.

Comment: @zfrisch I see that. But data-interchange formats have been specified to *not* have situations like this. Invalid JSON is not JSON at all. And if the source generates garbage like that, how do you know that it won't generate some more garbage that will break your fix? If you can't change the product, then replace the producer.

Comment: @str, I specifically said I can NOT change the source because the data I got is from a third party web service. Are you saying I need to go ask them to fix their problem?

Comment: @Lin Yes that is exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes, asking them to fix their problem should have been the first step. You only resort to trying to modify invalid json if there's no other option.

Comment: And in that situation, the most i would do with it is replacing `"Customer"` and '"Address"' with `"CustomerN"` and `"AddressN"` incrementing, and do any further manipulation after you've converted it to an object.

Comment: .@str, That was really a rhetorical question. If I could, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Why would this give error at char 50? `let newStr = JSON.stringify(str);
newStr = newStr.replace(/\\"Customers\\": {\\n/,"\"Customers\": [\\n")
      .replace(/},\\n  \\"Addresses\\"/,"],\\n  \"Addresses\"")
      .replace(/\\"Customer\\":/g,"")
`

Comment: What prevents you to ask them? Or are you phising the data ..?

Comment: @Teemu, I am not phishing the data, I have a really tight project deadline, and they have no intentions of fixing the problem anytime soon.

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks. that's the idea I want to hear not ask me why not to ask someone to fix the problem.

Comment: @Lin to be fair, you never specified that you had already asked them to fix it. Saying you *can't* isn't quite the same. It would be incorrect of us to steam forward assuming you already have asked that.

Comment: I would be veeeery careful with regular expressions on this. Instead I would try to use [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/) that *might* be able to handle JSON-like documents.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i kept it to just replacing the keys. That should be relatively safe, as any instance of "Customer" or "Address" inside a value would have the quotes escaped in some way and it won't be impacted by whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all other pathways of getting this fixed at the source has failed, I would suggest numerating the keys of Customers and Addresses, then doing any other manipulation of the json after you've converted it to an object.

```js
const str = `{
  "Description": "some descriptions",
  "Customers": {
        "Customer": {
              "Name": "John Smith",
              "Phone": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "Customer": {
              "Name": "Chris Lee",
              "Phone": "555-666-7890"
        }
  },
  "Addresses": {
        "Address": {
              "City": "New York"
        }
  }
}`;
let cCount = 0;
let aCount = 0;
const out = str.replace(/("Customer"|"Address")/g, function (a) {
  if (a === '"Customer"') {
    return `"Customer${cCount++}"`;
  } else {
    return `"Address${aCount++}"`;
  }
});
console.log(out);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

At that point you can `JSON.parse` the result and manipulate it like any other javascript object and convert those objects to arrays if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the source data fixed, here is a function that will turn child elements into arrays:

```
function makeArrays(json, pairs) {
    for (i in pairs) {
        // Turn container into array
        re = new RegExp(pairs[i][0]+'": {');
        json = json.replace(re, pairs[i][0]+'": [');

        // Remove label from child element
        re = new RegExp('"'+pairs[i][1]+'": ', 'g');
        json = json.replace(re, '');
    }
    // Close array
    json = json.replace(/} }/g, '} ]');

    return json;
}
```

This function takes two arguments. The first is the original JSON string, and the second is pairs of the container and child element labels.

The invocation looks like this:

```
makeArrays(jsonInput, [['Customers', 'Customer'],['Addresses', 'Address']])
```

And the output will be:

```
{ "Description": "some descriptions", "Customers": [ { "Name": "John Smith", "Phone": "123-456-7890" }, { "Name": "Chris Lee", "Phone": "555-666-7890" } ], "Addresses": [ { "City": "New York" } ] }
```

Which is valid JSON.